# Babel error caused by reference to "process"

Tags: node.js, babeljs, yarnpkg

I've found myself in a strange predicament—after a recent upgrade to my local app dependencies, the application breaks whenever I make reference to the node `process` object. Specifically it throws the following errors:
[`Babel Error: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNj15.png)

So far, I've tried to resolve this issue with a `yarn add` of the missing dependency, without success. Could anyone shed light on the issue at hand, or how I might be able to resolve it?

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by deleting `node_modules` and running `yarn install`.